# Thesis theme adding a div

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

How do I add a div between the header area and content area of a thesis theme. What is the code I need to write in `custom_functions.php` file to do this? If that's not the place, where do I need to make changes to get this done?

Comment: This question is very poorly worded. Where did this `custom_functions.php` come from? What framework are you working in? Heck, what is a "thesis theme"?

Comment: @Domenic: My understanding is that it is a Wordpress theme, I retagged the question accordingly

Comment: @ Domenic please refer this http://thesisthemetools.com/basic-php-syntax-for-custom_functions-php/

Comment: [A bit OT] I just followed that link and the page layout is quite a mess when seen on my system (FC12, FF 3.6.3). I would definitely choose another theme. They don't seem to be able to make their website cross-browser compatible...

Comment: I am almost _positive_ one of their screencast tutorials illustrates what you want step by step. The problem? There are many of them, each is 30 minutes long and I'm not sure which one mentioned it :)

Answer (score 3):

In your custom_functions.php file add the following code:

```
function my_div()
{
     echo '<div>Some new DIV between the header and content</div>';
}

add_action('thesis_hook_after_header', 'my_div');
```

You my want to reference [Thesis Hooks](http://www.thesishooks.com) and the [DIYThemes](http://www.diythemes.com) site for more specific Thesis help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the theme files. Probably the `header.php` and the one where the one which contains the body. Before you fire off questions like this, please read through http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development.

Comment: This is incorrect. Thesis is a Theme Framework for WordPress and moves away from the traditional method of theme development in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

One really easy way, is to use Thesis Openhooks. Select the one that's between the header and the content area.  I use that method all the time, especially for images.  Inside the hook, all you have to do is type the HTML code for the DIV (I tried to type it here, but the code disappeared after I posted the comment) and then I can add CSS code to it in custom.css. Hope this helps :)